# How can I configure the cancel button of dialog box bash?

Tags: bash, shell

How can I configure the cancel button of dialog box bash?

It follows what I've done till now:

```
dialog --backtitle "Dialog - Form sample" \
--form " Form Test - use [up] [down] to select input field " 21 70 18 \
"Network-ID:" 2 2 "" 2 15 20 0\
"Subnet Mask:" 4 2 "" 4 15 20 0\
```

Comment: Is that the whole command? If so, remove the trailing `\\` after "Subnet Mask:"

Comment: you also need a space between 0 and \ on the next to last line

Answer (score 0):

`--form` should provide it's own cancel button, however your syntax as quoted above should be

```
dialog --backtitle "Dialog - Form sample" \
--form " Form Test - use [up] [down] to select input field " 21 70 18 \
"Network-ID:" 2 2 "" 2 15 20 0 \
"Subnet Mask:" 4 2 "" 4 15 20 0
```